# EF4 context creation in one method

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4

I have many methods like this:

```
    public IEnumerable<Director> GetAllDirectors()
    {
        using (var dbContext = new BodModelContainer())
        {
            return dbContext.Members.OfType<Director>().ToList();
        }
    }
```

..or this..

```
    public Member GetMemberById(int memberId)
    {
        using(var dbContext = new BodModelContainer())
        {
            return dbContext.Members.Find(new[] {memberId});
        }
    }
```

or that:

```
    public SomeType GetOrDoSomethingWithDbBySomethingElse(T1 t1var, T2, T2 var, ...)
    {
        using(var dbContext = new BodModelContainer())
        {
            return dbContext.SomeType.DoSomething();
        }
    }
```

So I wanna reorganize all of these methods something like:

```
    // create db context here
    public void InDb(Func<BodModelContainer, out SomeGenericType???> workingWithDb)
    {
         using(var dbContext = new BodModelContainer())
         {
             workingWithDb(dbContext);
         }
    }

    // using it like
    public Member GetMemberById(int memberId)
    {
            InDb((dbContext) => 
            { 
                    return dbContext.Members.Find(new[] { memberId }); 
            });
    }
```

**Question**: How to make such generic `InDb` method, what is `SomeGenericType???`

Comment: this looks like unreadable abstraction

Comment: Eranga, Some sources edited. Is it more readable now? Or it's just bad idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The actual problem it looks like you're describing is the fact that you can't figure out how to set the return type of the `Func<>`. To be able to make this generic you'll need to make `InDb` require a generic type as well.

```
public TRet InDb<TRet>(Func<BodModelContainer, TRet> workingWithDb) {
  TRet ret = default(TRet);
  using (var dbContext = new BodModelContainer()) {
    ret = workingWithDb(dbContext);
  }
  return ret;
}

public Member GetMemberById(int memberId) {
  return InDb(dbContext => { return dbContext.Members.Find(new[] { memberId }); });
}
```

Should work (all the code here is untested), or using anonymous methods you could have a local variable and make .Net do all the nasty work.

```
public void InDb(Action<BodModelContainer> workingWithDb) {
  using (var dbContext = new BodModelContainer()) {
    workingWithDb(dbContext);
  }
}

public Member GetMemberById(int memberId) {
  Member member;
  InDb(dbContext => { member = dbContext.Members.Find(new[] { memberId }); });
  return member;
}
```

Of course, this all being said, I don't know if this level of redirection/abstraction is useful - you're making it slightly more complicated with little perceptible gain (if any). Unless there is a lot of work setting up and tearing down the `dbContext` used in `InDb` I don't think it is very helpful.

Comment: Drat - you beat me to it.  My answer was essentially identical to yours so I deleted it.  But I think this kind of thing is very useful, I do it all the time. It abstracts the (complex and repeated) setup/teardown code, and let's you deal only with the syntax of the code that finds the Member.  Looking at the same code repeated code, and mentally separating that from the code that does the work, tends to give me a headache after a few hours.  :)

Comment: @HiredMind: I agree, they can definitely be useful if there is some actual setup and teardown involved. If it's literally just encapsulating a "using" statement I don't see how replacing one piece of repeated code with another helps - unless you're planning for expanding in the future. That being said, I've definitely used this method myself to group together multiple operations where just the middle operation had to change. :)

Comment: @Joshua Actually my case is more complex. It's not only 'var dbContext = new BodModelContainer()' in using, but there are resolving connection string also. This is the first point to exctract 'using'-block in separate method. The second one - to have one point of creation dbContext.